# How can I make Vim autosave files when it loses focus?

Tags: vim

I'm used to my editors autosaving files when they lose focus.  I recently switched to MacVim, and I can't recreate that behavior.  I tried this:

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * wall
```

but if a buffer is unnamed when the window or MacVim loses focus, I get an error like the following:

```
Error detected while processing BufLeave Auto commands for "*":
E141: No file name for buffer 1
```

I'm confused, because `:wall`'s documentation says:

```
Write all changed buffers.  Buffers without a file
name or which are readonly are not written.
```

so I'd expect it to skip unnamed buffers.  Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**:

I'm pretty sure that the better way to do what I intended by using `BufLeave` -- saving buffers when I switch between them, so I don't get "No write since last change" -- is to set `'autowriteall'`.  The question still stands for when MacVim loses focus to other applications (`FocusLost`).

Comment: Just throwing this out there in regards to autosaving in VIM: aren't swap files enough?

Comment: I'm not trying to back up my work; I need the file to be on disk for whatever tool I've switched focus to, such as a test suite.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don’t care about errors in those circumstances since there is nothing you can reasonably do about them anyway – especially when losing focus. So just swallow them:

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * silent! wall
```

Much simpler than an elaborate dance to figure out where there *would* be an error in order to avoid it.

Comment: It needs a *, like   `autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * silent! wall`   , at least for me, it does.

Comment: vim noob here.. where does this line go? inside .vimrc?

Comment: Does it matter where in .vimrc it's added? This line does not make the warning go away for me.  :(

Comment: Uhm, hard to answer. It can matter, though in most cases won’t. What warning do you get? Is your vimrc posted anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect when docs for `wall` say "without a file name" they may be referring to buffers with buftype=nofile .  One way to get what you want would be to have the autocmd have bufdo call a simple function. E.g., some untested code to give the idea:

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * bufdo! call WriteFile()

function WriteFile()
   if (&buftype=="") && (expand("%:r") > "") && (&readonly==0)
      write
   endif
endfunction
```

I think the standard way of getting something like this automatic saving of buffers would be to set the `autosave` option in Vim.

Comment: `bufdo` will switch buffers in the current window. You should probably write `let s:curbuf=bufnr('%') | try | execute 'bufdo! call WriteFile()' | finally | execute "buffer ".s:curbuf | endtry`. It still has problems: for some reason after this code `list` option in help buffer was reset and cursor got positioned in the center. Adding `wincmd v` before `try` and `wincmd q` after `endtry` works better.

Comment: Plain `wincmd v | execute 'bufdo! call WriteFile()' | wincmd q` is probably the best option.

Comment: @ZyX -- Thanks for the correction; I wasn't thinking when I suggested bufdo.  Sounds like your second solution would work fine, opening new window, cycling through buffers, then closing window.  I still think just going with `autosave` is best solution, or possibly writing a more complex function to be called by the autocmd that uses a `windo` command within a `tabdo` so that buffer switching within a window is never required.

Answer (score 0):

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * bufdo! call WriteFile()

function WriteFile()
   if (&buftype=="") && (expand("%:r") > "") && (&readonly==0)
      write
   endif
endfunction
```

This method has a side-effect that, you can only open one unamed buffer. If you open the second one, it would automatically be synced to the content of the first unamed buffer.

Comment: This is a copy of Herbert Sitz's answer above with different commentary.  Was this intended as a comment on his answer?

Answer (score 0):

just put this in .vimrc

```
set updatetime=1000
autocmd CursorHoldI * silent w
```

Comment: That has several issues: first, it takes a full second to save, by which time I'd want to have the file on disk already; second, it only works if you stay in insert mode; third, `:write` doesn't cut it. @Aristotle Pagaltzis answer covers it for me.