# How to make VIM automatically save the file when changing focus to :terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal

I just started learning VIM. I was wondering if there's a any way to make VIM work similarly like VScode save "onFocusChange". Is there any thing I can do in .vimrc file? While working in C/C++ I use :terminal to compile program (constantly changing the focus between code and terminal using ctrl+w w), but sometimes I just forget to save the file. It would be much easier to make VIM do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to autosave in Vim 7 when focus is lost from the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087582/how-to-autosave-in-vim-7-when-focus-is-lost-from-the-window)

Comment: Hi! This solution kinda works. It saves file while jumping between :term and code in vim, but there is `sidefect`. When I need to ,for example, check something on the web (thus changing tab), file also saves. It's fine but I would much preffer to not have this functionality.

Comment: I had idea to append `:write` to `CTRL+W` command in .vimrc, but I ended up overwrting basic functionality of jumping between :term and vim.

Comment: Maybe the [answers to this question on Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/74/is-it-possible-to-make-vim-auto-save-files) could point you in the right direction? In general though, I'd prefer `:make` to `:terminal` for compiling.